# Determine which fields are dirty on an SQLAlchemy object

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know that, using SQLAlchemy's `session` object I can call `session.dirty` to get all objects with changes that need to be committed to the database.  But how can I determine which specific fields on any one object are dirty?  Is there a method I can call on the specific object that returns these fields?  Or maybe I can pass the object into one of `session`'s class methods to get this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An example from the [`History`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.History) class:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

hist = inspect(myobject).attrs.myattribute.history
```

If you wanted to check all defined attributes for a given object instance, you probably could do something like this:

```
def print_changes(myobj):
    from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
    from sqlalchemy import inspect
    inspr = inspect(myobj)
    attrs = class_mapper(myobj.__class__).column_attrs  # exclude relationships
    for attr in attrs:
        hist = getattr(inspr.attrs, attr.key).history
        print(attr.key, hist.has_changes())
```

Answer (score 0):

## That is not exact answer to your question, but you might like that one

```py
_MT = TypeVar("_MT", SAModel)

class BaseRepository(Generic[_MT]):
    _model: type[_MT]

    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession) -> None:
        self._session = session

    ...

    async def save(self, instance: _MT) -> _MT:
        """
        Save a new model instance or update if exists
        """
        inspr = inspect(instance)
        if not inspr.modified and inspr.has_identity:
            return instance

        self._session.add(instance)
        await self._session.flush()
        await self._session.refresh(instance)

        return instance
```